# Android FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception

I ported a Java Application to Android and everything is working fine, except that the App isn't able to load a .csv-file on my phone. It alway gives me the FileNotFoundException. Could anyone please help me? Any help is appreciated. Here is the buggy part of the code:

```
private String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getAbsolutePath() + "/Autoliste.csv";

public Auto[] lesenAutos() {
    int size = 0;
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            size++;
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        if (size == 0)
            System.out.println("Datei ist leer");
        reader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file");
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("Ungültige Zeichen vorhanden");
    }

    Auto[] arr = new Auto[size];
    int i = 0;
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        String zeile = reader.readLine();
        while (zeile != null) {
            arr[i] = new Auto();
            arr[i].setAuto(zeile);
            i++;
            zeile = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Datei nicht gefunden");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Lesefehler in Datei");
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Thanks, Tom.

Comment: Do you have the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission?

Comment: No, since it is my first App, I don't know how to add it. How can I add it?

Comment: Go to your AndroidManifest.xml file, and add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: No probs, glad I could help

Answer (score 4):

probably you are missing to add the package name of your application with `context.getPackageName()`

```
private String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + context.getPackageName() +  "/Autoliste.csv";
```

and be sure to have into your `AndroidManifest.xml` defined the next permission!:)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks, the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> was already enough to make it work :)

Comment: @ToTom, bear in mind if your not actually writing to the storage, just reading, it's probably better to use `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` instead, although using `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` will implicitly give you the READ permission anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but I also need to write to the external storage at a later stage.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error, and I finally realized that when I changed the file I was using in my app, I forgot to add '.csv' to the end of the new file name.  As soon as I added that, the error was gone.  Make sure to include the file type!  The devil is in the details.  I wouldn't have added this answer, but I figured some novice similar to me could make the same mistake down the road.